# Inline svg border bug

Tags: html, css, svg

I am struggling with a strange problem for a couple of days now. I am using big triangles in my website. I know if i make triangles in png or any other format, there is a big chance this is gonna look crispy. Thats why i go for the svg approach.

The first thing i approached was a big border under the svg elements. This was fixed by simply adding `vertical-align: top;` to the svg element.

The problem is that it is very buggy in some browsers. Some browsers show a line beneath it when resizing. Sometimes the line is always there.

The following image illustrates the problem, this is taking in safari 10.1 when resized:
[image]

This is how it should be
[image]

The svg are absolutely positioned i

Is there anyone who has faced this problem before and can help me out with this?

Comment: why you can use ::before and ::after element it's batter and easy .

Comment: Sure i can use before or after, but i don't see why its better. I think this not fixes anything.

Comment: Fiddle it. Otherwise is hard to say anything concrete.

Comment: If you want help you're going to need to create a [mcve] so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Try it while resizing safari. On iphone the problem occurs in **portrait mode** on any browser. New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t8f8rexv/6/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you're help guys, really appreciate it!

I ended up with a (dirty) fix.

The elements that are aligned to the bottom i gave a `transform: translate(0, 0.4px);`

And the elements that are aligned to the top i gave a `transform: translate(0, -0.4px);`

For now this seems a good fix without disrupting  the layout!